# Why does this code print something different depending on the indentation?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, indentation

I noticed that when the `print(msg)` is not indented inside the `for` loop and is indented on the same place as the for loop then it only prints the information from the update statement I did, but when it is the way it is down below it works how it should be giving me the information I requested.

Here is my code:

```py
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')

with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_roster(\
        col_name TEXT, \
        col_species TEXT, \
        col_iq TEXT \
        )")
    conn.commit()

with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_roster(col_name, col_species, col_iq) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", ('Jean-Baptiste Zorg', 'Human', '122'))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_roster(col_name, col_species, col_iq) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", ('Korben Dallas', 'Meat Popsicle', '100'))
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_roster(col_name, col_species, col_iq) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", ("Ak'not", 'Mangalore', '-5'))
    conn.commit()


with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE tbl_roster SET col_species=? WHERE col_name=? AND col_iq=?",('Human', 'Korben Dallas', '100'))
    conn.commit()


with conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT col_name, col_iq FROM tbl_roster WHERE col_species = 'Human'")

    varSpecies = cur.fetchall()
    for item in varSpecies:
        msg = "Name: {} \nIQ: {}  ".format(item[0], item[1])
        print(msg)
```

Comment: Please post your code as text! Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Give a [mre] **as text**, but probably: because indentation has meaning in Python.

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry, sorry didn't know that screenshots weren't accepted on Stack Overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Python uses indentation to define blocks. If you indent the `print` line under the `for` loop, it will be called on every iteration. If you don't, the loop will iterate and overwrite `msg` in each iteration, and then when it completes the `print` statement will print the last value.